# Float should have 5 leading numbers and no decimals

Tags: python, floating-point-precision

I need to convert a user inputted float into a 5 digit number that has no decimals to calculate the mantissa and exponent of the float

Example :- a input of: 12 Mantissa: 12000   Exponent: -3

but I can only find information on `math.frexp(x)` which I cant use for my assignment. Basically I need a way to convert the users input into a 5 digit mantissa but i am completely out of ideas and cant figure out how to properly convert the float so that it will work in calculations for the exponent. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if the input is 1234567? You will omit the extra 2 digits?

Comment: yeah it would omit the 2 extra digits, basically its supposed to be able to take any number and make a 5 digit mantissa

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if it is right, if you find the number of digits in the input and then multiplying the input with required powers of 10 gives you mantissa.

Answer (score 0):

Am not much inclined to give you exactly what you need (to help you learn on your own), but if you study the following code, you might get what you need.

```
def func(user_input):
    user_in = str(user_input)
    if not '.' in user_in: # Make the input as float
        user_in = user_in + '.'
    try:
        float(user_in)
    except:
        return ValueError

    decimal_pos = user_in.find('.')
    no_digits = decimal_pos

    if no_digits == 5:
        exponent = 0
        mantissa = int(user_in[:decimal_pos])
    elif no_digits > 5:
        exponent = 5 - no_digits
        mantissa = int(user_in[:decimal_pos])//(10**(-exponent))
    else:
        if no_digits == 1 and user_in[0] == '0':
            exponent = 5
        else:
            exponent = 5 - no_digits

        if len(user_in) >= decimal_pos+exponent+2:
            mantissa = int(user_in[:decimal_pos+exponent+2].replace('.',''))
        else:
            mantissa = int(user_in.replace('.','')) * (10**(decimal_pos+exponent+1 - len(user_in)))

    if float(user_in) == 0:
        exponent = 0
        mantissa = 0

    return mantissa, exponent

for a in (1.2345, 0.12345, 12, 12345, 123456, 123456.78):
    print a, func(a)
```

Output of the above

```
1.2345 (12345, 4)
0.12345 (12345, 5)
12 (12000, 3)
12345 (12345, 0)
123456 (12345, -1)
123456.78 (12345, -1)
```